# Why can't I read user input properly inside a UNIX while loop?

Tags: unix, shell

I'm using the bourne shell in UNIX, and am running into the following problem:

```
#!/bin/sh


while read line
   do

  echo $line

  if [ $x = "true" ]
  then
        echo "something"
        read choice
        echo $choice
  else
        echo "something"
  fi

done <file.txt
```

The problem I have here is that UNIX will not wait for user input in the read command - it just plows on through instead of waiting for what the user types in. How can I make unix wait for user input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are asking the program to read from the file `file.txt`:

```
done <file.txt
```

Also looks like you have a typo here:

```
if [ $x = "true" ]
     ^^
```

which should be `"$line"`. 
Also note the `"`, without them your program will break if the word read from the file has a space in it.

Answer (score 2):

The redirection of standard input by the `<file.txt` at the end of `while` ... `done <file.txt` affects the whole `while` loop, including the `read choice` as well as the `read line`.  It's not just failing to stop - it's consuming a line of your input file too.

Here's one way to solve the problem...

You can save the original standard input by using the somewhat obscure (even by shell standards):

```
exec 3<&0
```

which opens file descriptor 3 to refer to the original file descriptor 0, which is the original standard input.  (File descriptors 0, 1 and 2 are standard input, output and error respectively.)  And then you can redirect just the input of `read choice` to come from file descriptor 3 by doing `read choice <&3`.

Complete working script (I wasn't sure where `x` was supposed to come from, so I just bodged it to make it work):

```
#!/bin/sh

x=true  # to make the example work

exec 3<&0

while read line
   do

  echo $line

  if [ $x = "true" ]
  then
        echo "something"
        read choice <&3
  else
        echo "something"
  fi

done <file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't do much shell scripting, but i think 'read choice' should be 'read $choice'